# make button invisible and claim space

Tags: android, button, invisible

Is it possible to make a button invisible and claim the usable space ?

I have three horizontal buttons. On start up it decides which of the three buttons should be visible but if the middle one is invisible and the two outer ones are not, it leaves a space between them, corresponding to the size of the button that's not there

I want to be able to move the two outer buttons to squeeze in and center

Any ideas

Mark

Comment: yes instead of making them invisible set their visibility to GONE then you can claim the space occupied by them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `View.GONE`.

> `public static final int GONE`
>
> Added in API level 1
>   This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any
>   space for layout purposes. Use with `setVisibility(int)` and
>   `android:visibility`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE

Answer (score 0):

Set this button's visibility to `View.GONE`.
From the documentation:

> public static final int GONE
>
> Added in API level 1
> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

Comment: I dont know whats going on I cant post any more questions and i cant find out why